# LinearLayout suitable to another LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-layout-weight

I have two linear layout inside `constrainLayout`,
The bottom linear layout includes buttons and its height is `wrap_content` and must be wrap, because sometimes I keep only 1 button and sometimes 2 buttons.

I would like to set height of the top linearLayout to max but without covering the 2nd layout.
So I decided to set match_parent to the first, but after that it covers the 2nd layout.

- I can't use weight/weightsum

  ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

Comment: make height of 1st linear layout to `0dp`  , which is match constraint

Comment: The whole idea of using `ConstraintLayout` is to flatten your view hierarchy for faster rendering. In your situation you are using it but still nest views inside `LinearLayout`. What's the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="11"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"
        " />
</LinearLayout>
```

try this added weight sum and weight to make layout in prportion

Comment: consider perhaps to explain what you changed or did, otherwise it's a bit hard for OP to learn what they did wrong

Comment: I can't use weight, because this solution imposes 1/10 of size for buttons container

Comment: wellweight are used for this particular scenario but nevertheless you can put everything in relative layout then it can be position relatively

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ConstraintLayout, you can set the height of the first LinearLayout to 0dp. The ConstraintLayout interprets it as "match constraints".
The next step would be to properly define the constraints of the first LinearLayout (which you did).

You can read more about ConstraintLayout [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="16dp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Button1" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Button2"
              android:visibility="gone" />
      </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to use a combination of linearlayout as parent and attribute layoutWeight ,If you use a constant value for layoutWeight for both top layout and button's container , then this will lead to some problem on different screen height devices , instead this solution make you able to set your buttons height as big as enough by setting its container's height to wrapContent and give all top area for the layout content .
You can also make the top linearLayout scrollable to get the best experience possible :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/this_layout_will_fil_all_space_except_the_bottom_layout_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_layout_at_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" 
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For Buttons , you can set its width to wrapContent and add gravity attribute to its parent as above , in this way even if one buttons was gone , the other will fit perfectly in the center of the container .

**Enjoy !**

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of using `ConstraintLayout` is to avoid using any other nested `ViewGroups`, The more you add more hierarchy in layout, the less performance you'll have. You can [check documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) for more.

So for performance wise it's better to add widgets/views directly within the `ConstraintLayout`.

So, here I removed the bottom `LinearLayout`, and kept only the buttons directly within the `ConstraintLayout`, you can do the same for the top `LinearLayout`, you can just add any underlying views directly to the `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: we cant remove linear layout, i have to use scroll view inside constraint